# Why does sh interpret shebang line as a command after $() substitution?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I want install on-my-zsh using a Python script, so I following the [unattended install](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh#unattended-install) from github. It use `sh -c` to download the install script and execute it using sh:

```
$ sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)" "" --unattended
```

I want to do it in `python` using `subprocess`, so I write this:

```py
    args = [
        "sh",
        "-c",
        "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
        "",
        "--unattended"
    ]
    p = subprocess.run(args, check=True)
```

However I got error and it says:

```
sh 1: #!/bin/sh: Not such file or directory
```

I guess it means sh interpret the shebang line a command.
How can it happen and how to avoid it?
Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: You need to execute the script with sh -c '/home/foo/test,sh'? Where /home/foo represents the actual path you the script

Comment: I edit my description. Could you recheck it?

Comment: You missed a `$` before `(curl…`. You should also use `shell=True` for subprocess.run.

Comment: @CyrillePontvieux Sorry the missing $ is just a typo. In python subprocess's doc, shell=True just means sh -c, so I don't think it's the crux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you needed two rounds of evaluation: one to expand the command substitution, then a second to treat it as shell code. If you had used single quotes in your shell command, you would have seen the same problem.

You can explicitly add an `eval`:

```
args = [
        "sh",
        "-c",
        "eval \"$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)\""
        "",
        "--unattended"
    ]
p = subprocess.run(args, check=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

What your command actually does;

- it runs `curl` in the current shell
- it then passes the quoted output from `curl` to `sh -c`

That is, the string inside the double quotes is the text of the script which `curl` already fetched.

What your Python code actually does is something different.

I would refactor it to just

```py
import requests
import subprocess

r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh')
subprocess.run(['sh'], input=r.text, text=True)
```

or perhaps, more literally copying the existing command,

```
subprocess.run(['sh', '-c', r.text, '', '--unattended'])
```

(`requests` is not strictly necessary here if you don't want to pull in a third-party library.

```py
from urllib3 import PoolManager as u3

r = u3().request('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh')
subprocess.run(['sh', '-c', r.data, '', '--unattended'])
```

but as you can see, using just the Python standard library is a bit more unwieldy.)